# как раскрасить с помощью Beatifulsoup распарсить следующий код:

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
[<a data-default-size="13px" href="/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/investigate">investigate</a>]
```

не совсем понимаю как распарсить данные внутри самого тега .
цель -  получить слово invistigate а так же ссылку href .

Пробовал

Answer (score 1):

```
href = soup.find('a").get('href')
text = soup.find('a").text
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]